# Can an ISO and live-usb be infected or compromised?

Tags: live-usb, iso, hacking

If yes, how and what are the signs? What should one do? Will the OS be compromised as well?

Comment: The instructions for using Ubuntu ISO's include a verification step (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) which can ensure (if followed) the ISO was not compromised during download.  When you boot a Ubuntu ISO it provides a check-install-media option which will re-run this verify step (checking for change or bad-writes).  Ubuntu has not suffered ISO infection (from official sites), but other distro's have, so these steps are worth doing (let alone the pick up errors & save tons of time wasted diagnozing problems that were just bad download or media-writes).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122910/will-the-iso-installed-on-the-live-usb-be-infected-if-made-with-a-compromised-ub ????

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for using Ubuntu ISO's include a verification step which can ensure (*if followed*) the ISO was not compromised during download. 
(https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

When you boot a Ubuntu ISO it provides a check-install-media option which will re-run this verify step (checking for change or bad-writes).
(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)

Ubuntu has not suffered ISO infection (from official sites), but other distro's have, so these steps are worth doing (let alone the pick up errors & save tons of time wasted diagnozing problems that were just bad download or media-writes).

Comment: Depending which ISO/Ubuntu release (or flavor) you are using the verify-install-media option isn't always obvious.  When you see the person-in-circle & keyboard logos/icons, you can press a key and a menu will appear providing that option (*it does not list for all languages, so if you're not using english & don't see it you may have a language which it the check-install-media hasn't been translated to*) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Answer (score 0):

I will answer about the live USB drive. @guiverc answered about the iso file.

If you

- **download** an Ubuntu iso file from the official Ubuntu web site,
- **check** it with md5sum,
- ***clone*** from it to a USB pendrive (for example with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator),

then you will have a read-only and live-only USB drive with the iso 9660 file system. It will not get infected.

---

There are several cloning tools.

- The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions is one of them. You can also use
- Disks alias `gnome-disks`
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (must be installed)
- `dd` - a powerful command line tool, that is risky (you can easily overwrite valuable data).

---

If you want a high level of security against corruption, you should not use extracting tools like Unetbootin or Rufus.